# How to define relations between models with a table of multi foreign keys

Tags: php, laravel

Each `Attribute` has multi `Option`s.
Each `Product` can has multi `attributes` and ***some*** `options`.

this is my table:

[image]

now I can fetch `attributes` and `options` of a `product` model this:

```
{
"id":1,
"product_title":"product 1",
"attributes":[
{
"id":1,
"title":"colors",
"options":[
{"id":1,"title":"red"},
{"id":2,"title":"green"},
]

}]
}
```

My tables:

```
products
id - product_title


product_options
id - option_id - attirbute_id - product_id

attributes
id - title

options
id - title - attibute_id
```

Comment: What's the name of that table?. Does the table, in particular, have an independent model?.

Comment: @DanielW. I don't want to define an attribute multiple times.

Comment: @DanielW. Each Product can has multi attributes and `some` options

Comment: I deleted my comment because I was thinking options are a part of attributes. You should anyways split dependencies. Make two tables: `product_has_attribute` and `product_has_option`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One suggestion is to refactor your tables in this sort of way.

`products` table

```
id - integer
product_title - string
```

`attributes` table

```
id – integer
title - string
```

`attribute_product` table

```
id – integer
attribute_id – integer
product_id – integer
```

`options` table

```
id - integer
title - string
```

`option_morphs` table

```
id - integer
option_id - integer
optionable_id - integer
optionable_type - string
```

Then your models would look like:

```php
class Product extends Model

{
    public function attributes()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Attribute::class);
    }

    public function optionMorphs()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(OptionMorph::class, 'optionable');
    }
}
```

```php
class Attribute extends Model
{
    public function optionMorphs()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(OptionMorph::class, 'optionable');
    }

    public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class);
    }
}
```

```php
class OptionMorph extends Model
{
    protected $table = "option_morphs";

    public function optionable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }

    public function option()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Option::class, "option_id", "id");
    }
    
}
```

```php
class Option extends Model

{

    public function optionMorphs()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(OptionMorph::class);
    }

}
```

## Example 1

```php
// Each Attribute has multi Options. Each Product can have multi attributes.

App\Models\Product::with(["attributes.optionMorphs.option"])->firstWhere("id", 1)
```

#### Output 1:

```php
/*
=> App\Models\Product {#3391
     id: 1,
     product_title: "mayonnaise",
     created_at: null,
     updated_at: null,
     attributes: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#4324
       all: [
         App\Models\Attribute {#4318
           id: 1,
           title: "colors",
           created_at: null,
           updated_at: null,
           pivot: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot {#4262
             product_id: 1,
             attribute_id: 1,
           },
           optionMorphs: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#4345
             all: [
               App\Models\OptionMorph {#4347
                 id: 1,
                 option_id: 3,
                 optionable_id: 1,
                 optionable_type: "App\Models\Attribute",
                 created_at: null,
                 updated_at: null,
                 option: App\Models\Option {#4358
                   id: 3,
                   title: "blue",
                   created_at: null,
                   updated_at: null,
                 },
               },
               App\Models\OptionMorph {#4350
                 id: 2,
                 option_id: 1,
                 optionable_id: 1,
                 optionable_type: "App\Models\Attribute",
                 created_at: null,
                 updated_at: null,
                 option: App\Models\Option {#4356
                   id: 1,
                   title: "red",
                   created_at: null,
                   updated_at: null,
                 },
               },
             ],
           },
         },
       ],
     },
   }
*/
```

### Example 2

```php
// Each Product can have some options.

App\Models\Product::with(["optionMorphs.option"])->firstWhere("id", 1)
```

#### Output 2

```php
/*
=> App\Models\Product {#4173
     id: 1,
     product_title: "mayonnaise",
     created_at: null,
     updated_at: null,
     optionMorphs: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#4069
       all: [
         App\Models\OptionMorph {#3701
           id: 3,
           option_id: 4,
           optionable_id: 1,
           optionable_type: "App\Models\Product",
           created_at: null,
           updated_at: null,
           option: App\Models\Option {#4343
             id: 4,
             title: "option random",
             created_at: null,
             updated_at: null,
           },
         },
       ],
     },
   }
 */
```

#### Migrations.

```php
// create_products_table.
// ...
        Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string("product_title");
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

```php
// create_attributes_table.
// ...
        Schema::create('attributes', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string("title");
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

```php
// create_attribute_product_table.
// ...
        Schema::create('attribute_product', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger("product_id");
            $table->unsignedBigInteger("attribute_id");
            $table->unique(["product_id", "attribute_id"]);

            $table->foreign("product_id")
                ->references("id")
                ->on("products")
                ->onDelete("cascade");

            $table->foreign("attribute_id")
                ->references("id")
                ->on("attributes")
                ->onDelete("cascade");
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

```php
// create_options_table.
// ...
        Schema::create('options', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string("title");
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

```php
// create_option_morphs_table.
// ...
        Schema::create('option_morphs', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger("option_id");
            $table->unsignedBigInteger("optionable_id");
            $table->string("optionable_type");
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign("option_id")
                ->references("id")
                ->on("options")
                ->onDelete("cascade");
        });
```

#### Edit

[Alternative solution below.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67794050/7376590)

Answer (score 0):

You need to define these models with the following relationships:

```php
class YourModel extends Model
{
    public function option()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Option::class);
    }

    public function attribute()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Attribute::class);
    }

    public function product()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Product::class);
    }
}
```

```php
class Attribute extends Model
{
    public function options()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Option::class);
    }
}
```

```php
class Product extends Model
{
    public function attributes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Attribute::class);
    }

    public function options()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Option::class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Having given the question a second look, I figured that probably this could be a simpler solution than my previous answer.

### Table Structure

`products` table

```
id - integer
product_title - string
```

`attributes` table

```
id – integer
title - string
```

`attribute_product` table

```
id – integer
attribute_id – integer
product_id – integer
```

`options` table

```
id - integer
title - string
```

`optionables` table

```
id - integer
option_id - integer
optionable_id - integer
optionable_type - string
```

### Models

```php
// Product model.

class Product extends Model

{
    public function attributes()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Attribute::class);
    }

    public function options()
    {
        return $this->morphToMany(Option::class, 'optionable');
    }
}
```

```php
// Attribute Model. 

class Attribute extends Model
{

    public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class);
    }

    public function options()
    {
        return $this->morphToMany(Option::class, 'optionable');
    }
}
```

```php
// Option model.

class Option extends Model

{

    public function attributes()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany(Attribute::class, 'optionable');
    }

    public function products()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany(Product::class, 'optionable');
    }

}
```

## Example 1

```php
// Each Attribute has multi Options. Each Product can have multi attributes.

App\Models\Product::with(["attributes.options"])->firstWhere("id", 1)
```

#### Output 1:

```php
/*
=> App\Models\Product {#4108
     id: 1,
     product_title: "mayonnaise",
     created_at: null,
     updated_at: null,
     attributes: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#4341
       all: [
         App\Models\Attribute {#4107
           id: 1,
           title: "colors",
           created_at: null,
           updated_at: null,
           pivot: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot {#4173
             product_id: 1,
             attribute_id: 1,
           },
           options: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#4346
             all: [
               App\Models\Option {#4343
                 id: 1,
                 title: "red",
                 created_at: null,
                 updated_at: null,
                 pivot: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphPivot {#4340
                   optionable_id: 1,
                   option_id: 1,
                   optionable_type: "App\Models\Attribute",
                 },
               },
               App\Models\Option {#4348
                 id: 3,
                 title: "blue",
                 created_at: null,
                 updated_at: null,
                 pivot: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphPivot {#4347
                   optionable_id: 1,
                   option_id: 3,
                   optionable_type: "App\Models\Attribute",
                 },
               },
             ],
           },
         },
       ],
     },
   }

*/
```

### Example 2

```php
// Each Product can have some options.

 App\Models\Product::with(["options"])->firstWhere("id", 1)
```

#### Output 2

```php
/*
=> App\Models\Product {#4339
     id: 1,
     product_title: "mayonnaise",
     created_at: null,
     updated_at: null,
     options: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#4172
       all: [
         App\Models\Option {#3378
           id: 4,
           title: "option random",
           created_at: null,
           updated_at: null,
           pivot: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphPivot {#4318
             optionable_id: 1,
             option_id: 4,
             optionable_type: "App\Models\Product",
           },
         },
       ],
     },
   }
 */
```

#### Migrations.

```php
// create_products_table.
// ...
        Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string("product_title");
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

```php
// create_attributes_table.
// ...
        Schema::create('attributes', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string("title");
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

```php
// create_attribute_product_table.
// ...
        Schema::create('attribute_product', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger("product_id");
            $table->unsignedBigInteger("attribute_id");
            $table->unique(["product_id", "attribute_id"]);

            $table->foreign("product_id")
                ->references("id")
                ->on("products")
                ->onDelete("cascade");

            $table->foreign("attribute_id")
                ->references("id")
                ->on("attributes")
                ->onDelete("cascade");
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

```php
// create_options_table.
// ...
        Schema::create('options', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string("title");
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

```php
// create_optionables_table.
// ...
        Schema::create('optionables', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger("option_id");
            $table->unsignedBigInteger("optionable_id");
            $table->string("optionable_type");
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->unique(["option_id", "optionable_id", "optionable_type"]);

            $table->foreign("option_id")
                ->references("id")
                ->on("options")
                ->onDelete("cascade");
        });
```

### Resources

[Many To Many (Polymorphic)](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations)

[Many To Many Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)

[Inserts for Many To Many Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships)

##### Add `options` to a `product`

```php
 App\Models\Product::find(1)->options()->sync([4, 5])
```

##### Add `options` to an `attribute`

```php
  App\Models\Attribute::find(1)->options()->sync([1,2,3])
```

##### Add `attributes` to a `product`

```php
  App\Models\Product::find(1)->attributes()->sync([1])
```